# Get all values of a ACF field in all posts and the links to the posts

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I have created an ACF field where I can add 1 keyword per post. I want to get now a list of all keywords set in all my posts and sort it by alphabet and add a link to the post where it was found. Every keyword will be unique. So it would be a kind of table of content. How can I do that programatically? I have no idea right now on how to loop through posts and get field values.

Comment: Hello. Asking for opinions is off topic for this site. If you can rework your question to include a coding example of what you've tried, then people will help you.

Comment: I changed the question a bit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ReneDasbeck, This should help :: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/ and this for orderding : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Place the following function in functions.php . Use it directly in your template or as shortcode or w/e

```
function keywords_post_list() {
    //We build our query for posts containing any value in meta field
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key'     => 'keyword', //change with your meta key
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args); 
    global $post;
    $items = array();
    if($query->have_posts()): 
        while($query->have_posts()):
            $query->the_post();
            //Looping each post we collect the keyword and the link for a post.
            //Grab any other information if you need and add in the array
            $keyword = get_post_meta($post->ID,'keyword',true);
            $link = get_the_permalink($post->ID);
            //Our array
            $items[] = array('keyword'=> $keyword,'link' => $link);
        endwhile;
    endif;
    // We need to sort results by keyword currently ASC
    array_multisort(array_column($items, 'keyword'), $items);

    // If we need to sort DESC uncommnet bellow coment above
    // array_multisort(array_column($items, 'keyword'),SORT_DESC, $items);

    // error_log(print_r($items,true));

    if($items):
        echo '<ol class="keyword-list">';
        foreach($items as $item):
            $keyword = $item['keyword'];
            $link = $item['link'];
            echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$keyword.'</a></li>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</ol>';
    endif;
}
```

Comment: I was searching for the same thing but on users and this led me to the following similar working solution, that might help somebody someday:

 ```new WP_User_Query(['meta_key' => 'keyword', 'meta_value' => '','meta_compare' => '!=']); ```